# OAuth2 server with an external user source

Tags: php, symfony, oauth, fosoauthserverbundle

I'm building an OAuth2 server with the great [FOSOAuthServer](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/issues/338)Bundle.

My Symfony app authentifies users coming from another source (actually another server).

I have created a custom `UserProvider` which works fine with the default Symfony security layer. I have my implementation of `UserInterface` but it's obviously not an Entity of the database.

Implementing the classes for [`AccessToken`](/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Model/AccessToken.php), [`RefreshToken`](/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Model/RefreshToken.php) & [`AuthCode`](/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Model/AuthCode.php) as [told in the installation instructions](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#doctrine-orm-classes) for Doctrine, I defined the user reference as

```php
//...
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $user_id;
//...
```

Does it seem logical until there ?

Now the true question is:
**Where do I specify the way to link my users to the different tokens ?**

---

*I've also been [asking the question](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSOAuthServerBundle/issues/338) on the official repo for visibility purpose*

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing 2 things:

- Overriding the tokens setter & getter for the property `user`
- Using a Doctrine `LifecycleEvent` listener

First extend the token classes (for example with a [Trait](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php))

```php
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use AppBundle\Security\User;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

trait AppTokenTrait
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @var string
     */
    protected $username;

    public function setUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof User) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                sprintf("User must be an instance of %s", User::class)
            );
        }

        $this->username = $user->getUsername();
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public function getUser()
    {
        if (!$this->user) {
            throw new \RuntimeException(
                "Unable to get user - user was not loaded by postLoad"
            );
        }

        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }
}
```

In the 3 token classes (And don't forget to update the database schema):

```
//...
    use AppTokenTrait;
//...
```

Create the listener

```php
namespace AppBundle\Services;

use AppBundle\Entity\AccessToken;
use AppBundle\Entity\AuthCode;
use AppBundle\Entity\RefreshToken;
use AppBundle\Security\UserProvider;
use Doctrine\ORM\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

class AppTokenListener
{
    /**
     * @var UserProvider
     */
    protected $userProvider;

    public function __construct(UserProvider $userProvider)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    public function postLoad(LifecycleEventArgs $event)
    {
        $object = $event->getObject();

        if (
            $object instanceof AccessToken or
            $object instanceof AuthCode or
            $object instanceof RefreshToken
        ) {
            $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($object->getUsername());
            $object->setUser($user);
        }
    }
}
```

Register it as a service

```
app.token.listener:
    class: AppBundle\Services\AppTokenListener
    tags:
        - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: postLoad }
```

The user object should now always be attached to the tokens

Comment: Hi Pierre, your post really helped me setting up a similar configuration. I have everything up and running from the oauth side, but calling my api with the access token leads in a fatal error:

"Error: Call to a member function loadUserByUsername() on a non-object" at ***/OAuthBundle/Services/SecurityTokenListener.php line 41, where line 41 is $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsername($object->getUsername());"

It seems, that the constructor is never called. Any idea, what's going on here?

Thanks, Chris

Comment: All I remember having here is a circular reference issue when injecting the `userProvider` into the listener, and I saw this was a known issue that I workedaround in a quite dirty way

Comment: Got it now, the service just needs the user provider as an argument and your AppTokenListener is missing a "_" at the constructor. Copy/Paste isn't a good idea:-)

Comment: How did you get past this circular reference thing?